# Jasmine.js Testing - spy on window.process

Tags: mocking, jasmine

How can I mock `window.process`

I tried this:

```
 spyOn(window, 'process').and.returnValue(value);
```

But it will return a linting error on process: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if you're absolutely sure that this should work for your situation, I just use the `as any` cast.

```
spyOn(window, 'process').and.returnValue(value as any);
```

I am assuming this is TypeScript.